# multidimensional array and display in expandable tabelview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, multidimensional-array

I am new to iphone technology. i want to make arrays for category and subcategory and display in tableview. 
if anyone clicked on particular category than it displays its subcategory values.  and i get this value dynemically from my api... there is no define that howmany records of this type i will get.......my format is something like as below.

```
Category id     Subcatid  
categoryId 1  subcategoryId 2 
              subcategoryId 3  
categoryId 4  subcategoryId 3 
              subcategoryId 4  
              subcategoryId 5 
              subcategoryId 6  
              subcategoryId 7
```

Comment: Do you want to display all information on a single tableview? For example the user taps on a 'category' cell and then dynamically you fetch the subcategories and load them under the cell or drill down the categories on separate tableviews?

Comment: yes i want exactly that thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample tutorials for expandable tableview i think it may help you.

1. [Mobile and Social Network Technology](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-does-uitableviewcell-reorder.html)
2. [KOTree](https://github.com/adamhoracek/KOTree)

Comment: On SO, when providing a link to an external site, it is often best to give at least a high level summary of what the contents are in case the external link changes or is deleted. Future SO visitors will still have *something* to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableArray one for category and other subCategory like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mut_arrcategory = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Category1",@"Category2", nil] // array content can be more.
NSMutableArray *mut_arrSubcategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SubCategory1",@"SubCategory2", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SubCategory3",@"SubCategory4",@"SubCategory5", nil], nil];
```

Here tableview will display Category1,Category2 and its subcategory will be arrays of content